# Apache 2 virtual host pointing to index.html

Tags: command-line, server, permissions, apache2, vim

I tried to create a virtual host `whitecrm.local` by the following procedure:

1. First I created host using
   `sudo vim /etc/hosts`

   ```
   127.0.0.1       localhost
   127.0.0.1       whitecrm.local
   ```
2. Created a file in `sites-available/whitecrm.local`

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
       ServerName whitecrm.local
       DocumentRoot /var/www/whitecrm_local

       <Directory />
           Options FollowSymLinks
           AllowOverride All
       </Directory>

       <Directory /var/www/whitecrm_local/>
           Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
           AllowOverride All
           Order allow,deny
           allow from all
       </Directory>

       ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/

       <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
           AllowOverride None
           Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
           Order allow,deny
           Allow from all
       </Directory>

       ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

       # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
       # alert, emerg.
       LogLevel warn

       CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

       Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
       <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
           Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
           AllowOverride None
           Order deny,allow
           Deny from all
           Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
       </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
3. Then restarted apache

   ```
   sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
   ```

When I tried `http://whitecrm.local` in my browser. It's pointing to `index.html` file from `/var/www`, not my new one in `/var/www/whitecrm_local`.

I checked `apache2.conf` file, It has the line uncommented:

```
Include sites-enabled/
```

What is the problem in here? and what am I missing?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu? Is there a link to `sites-available/whitecrm.local` in `sites-enabled`?

Comment: I am using ubuntu 12.04. Yes it shows like this: lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   26 Dec  8 23:09 000-default -> ../sites-available/default.

Comment: @GaneshBabu.T.Y that... doesn't look like the correct item.  That's the default config, we're looking for one that matches `../sites-enabled/whitecrm.local`.

Comment: Could you try to disable `000-default` using `a2dissite` command, and check if `whitecrm.local` works? It could be a misconfiguration problem.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't just drop stuff into `sites-enabled`.  You should use `a2ensite` to enable the site configuration in Apache.

The syntax is `a2ensite [site]`.

Comment: I've already tried the same in my system and got it worked. It's only after re-installing the OS(Ubuntu 12.04), I got stuck with this error

Comment: With the last update, the root for the html files changed from /var/www to /var/www/html Try and check if the problem is related to that.